# ASP.NET Forms Authentication and AJAX requests handling in Login Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Application that uses Forms Authentication. In the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/App/Account/Login" name=".AppAuthCookie" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10080" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Then in the Account Controller:

```
// GET: /Account/Login
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

// GET: /Account/Login
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    // if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    // {
    //     HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    // }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Things work fine until I use a jQuery AJAX call. It doesn't matter if I'm getting data via a different controller, or trying to get data from a .cshtml template file... as soon as I make the call, it hits the 2nd /Account/Login method and it returns the login page NO MATTER WHAT. Even if I've logged in 5 seconds ago.

Everywhere I've looked, people offered hacks for changing the ResponseCode to 401 and to use Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect for AJAX calls. But no luck.

It seems to me that our Login logic is wrong. Maybe /Account/Login shouldn't return an ActionResult View. If that's correct, how should this logic work, and how can I make sure that AJAX calls will work correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to get data back from the server or navigate to a page on the site ?

Comment: I think that's my mistake. When hitting /account/login, I want to get the login page. But whenever I create an ajax call (meant to hit a separate controller to get data), it hits the /account/login controller and attempts to return the view. I don't know how to make it NOT hit the login controller.

Comment: So it seems like it's going to hit the authentication regardless. I figure the login logic needs to be changed.

Comment: Once logged in your Ajax shouldn't be pushing you back to the log in page . If you are trying to get data back from the server use a Json result and not an actionresult then use jQuery/JavaScript to read the information and do what you will with it . But what could be happening is that the methods you are calling with Ajax are not using the [authorize] attribute above the method name . I could be wrong though.

Comment: Method name sorry not class name

Comment: Can you post a sample of how you are doing the ajax request?

Comment: Are you setting up authentication cookie?

Comment: Hi all. Thank you for the help and time. It ended up coming down to an Auth Cookie issue. We have a "sub-site" on a Virtual Directory. So we had to set matching MachineKeys on both projects to make the auth cookies work correctly. All good now. Thanks again!

Comment: please post the ajax call